# Php Script only returning last value

Tags: php, sql, database

Hey I have the following script that is not working and its getting late for me so I could use some help. This receives an array of id's from an http post and is supposed to grab the user names. When sending it a single Id which I know is in my database I get null back. Whats wrong with my script?

```
<?php
$friendArray[] = $_POST["friendId"];

$hostname = 'http://localhost/';
$dbname = 'MYDB';
$db_username = 'user';
$db_password = 'pass';
$options = array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8', );

$inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($friendArray), '?'));

try {
    $dsn = "mysql:unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock;dbname=".$dbname;
    $dbh = new PDO( $dsn, $db_username, $db_password, $options);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT USER_SCREEN_NAME USER WHERE USER_ID IN (' . $inQuery . ')');
    foreach ($friendArray[] as $k => $friend)
    {
        $sth->bindValue(($k+1), $friend);
    } 
    $sth->execute();
    $results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json=json_encode($results);
    echo $json;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$dbh = null;

?>
```

Solution: The main problem I found was there was no "FROM" in the sql statement. After that I went through a bunch more iterations and problems finally getting to the following which worked. Another issue was that looping and binding was not working, so once I got the array in the proper format passing it in execute did the trick.

```
<?php
$friendArray = array();
foreach ($_POST["friendId"] as $myFriend)
{
    $friendArray[] = $myFriend;
}

$hostname = 'http://localhost/';
$dbname = 'MYDB';
$db_username = 'user';
$db_password = 'pass';
$options = array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8', );

$inQuery = implode('', array_fill(0, count($friendArray)-1, " OR USER_ID = ?"));

try {
    $dsn = "mysql:unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock;dbname=".$dbname;
    $dbh = new PDO( $dsn, $db_username, $db_password, $options);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT USER_SCREEN_NAME FROM USER WHERE USER_ID = ?" . $inQuery . "");
    $sth->execute($friendArray);
    $results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json=json_encode($results);
    echo $json;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$dbh = null;

?>
```

Comment: Which rows in this script does not work as expected?

Comment: Probably way off here, but what is the reason for the square brackets in `$friendArray[] = $_POST["friendId"];`? Won't that just assign `$_POST["friendId"]` to `$friendArray[0]`?

Comment: @cegfault See how `$inQuery` is populated; that's not SQL injection at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part in your code:

```
foreach ($friendArray[] as $k => $friend)
```

Causes a syntax error. `$friendArray` should not have the square brackets `[]` here:

```
foreach ($friendArray as $k => $friend)
```

Comment: when I make that change I get a syntax error near "WHERE USER_ID IN (?)" So it looks like the bindValue is not working when I do this.

Comment: Then why not just pass the values directly via execute()?

Comment: I added the solution to my main post. Passing it in execute helped but there were still problems with the SQL and how I was getting the array from POST. Thanks